# Godot engine not working on mac

Tags: debugging, opengl-es, 2d, game-engine, godot

I am trying to get started with Godot. Unfortunately right out of the box I am having problems following the most basic tutorial on their page. When I try to run a scene containing a label with "Hello World", or indeed just the icon they provide dragged into the middle of the page, nothing happens after I press the "play" button. The window that pops up doesn't display anything. The console gives me this error:

```
Remote Debugger: Connection failed with status: '2', retrying in 1 msec.
OpenGL ES 3.0 Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6490M OpenGL Engine
```

I have tried this same thing on my other computer which is an iMac slightly newer and it works, so my question is: is there a problem with the hardware? I am running godot on a 2011 MacBook pro that as far as I can tell has OpenGL 4.1 (Godot requires 3.0). I say as far as I can tell because all I could find is a page from apple with a table saying what my model of MacBook pro runs for OpenGl. I did try asking the terminal for my openGl version with this command:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

But it comes back with "command not found".

I have also had a look at the editor settings under debug and Remote Host is set at 127.0.0.1 and Remote port at 6005.

I don't know what any of this means. Please any help appreciated.

Comment: The console says something about OpenGL **ES** 3.0. This is not the same as OpenGL 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to share that I found the answer in case this is happening to you. I just changed the Remote port number. Not sure why this was giving a debug problem and also particularly not sure why a debug issue should stop the running of the project. So if anyone with more experience can throw some light into the matter that would be great.